# Page overwritten in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to navigate around pages in jQuery Mobile and I am having trouble with dynamically created page and ajax loaded ones.

I have a page (`page_2`) from which I dynamically create a page (`page_3`) by using `page3.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);` and then `$.mobile.changePage(page3);`. It works fine and I can go back to `page_2` by doing `$.mobile.changePage($("#page_2"));`. So far so good.

The problem is when I land in `page_2` from another page (eg `page_1`). It this case, for some reason, `page_2` disappears from `$.mobile.pageContainer` when I create `page_3` (whereas `page_1` remains). It prevents me from going back from the newly created page to `page_2` where it technically belongs.

Any idea why? Is there any way I can prevent `page_2` from being removed?

**You can try it out there: [page_1](http://caractereschinois.free.fr/page_1.html) and [page_2](http://caractereschinois.free.fr/page_2.html)**

In short:
`page_1 -> page_2` works
`page_1 -> page_2 -> page_3` works
`page_1 -> page_2 -> page_3 -> page_2` fails
`page_2 -> page_3 -> page_2 -> page_3` works (however many loops you like)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `data-dom-cache` attribute to `true` on the `<div data-role="page" id="page_2">` element (the second page) so it isn't removed once it's navigated away from:

```
<div data-dom-cache="true" data-role="page" id="page_2">
    ...
</div>
```

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/data-attributes.html

jQuery Mobile's default behavior is to remove any pseudo-page from the DOM that was brought in by AJAX after the user navigates away from it. So when you link to remote documents, use absolute links that point to the URL of the document, not the ID of it's `<div data-role="page">` element.

Your dynamically created page three uses this to navigate back to the second page:

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#page_2"));
```

It could change to:

```
$.mobile.changePage('/page_2.html');
```

If you link to pages like this, they will by default be removed from the DOM after they are navigated away from, the idea is that you are less likely to crash a mobile device's browser if there are minimal pages in the DOM. There is also the chance that the page will just be pulled in from cache so no HTTP request is made in that case.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense and fixes my problem. I will be careful resorting to data-dom-cache but it comes as a huge help. My site is organized around pages that require heavy data transfer and pages that are just there to display data. I try to the latter dynamic to avoid redoing the data transfer but jQuery mobile is not very natural for that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the jqm events for this:

```
$("#page3link").click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    createPage3();
    return false;
});
```

you'll need to do the same for the go back to button 2 link or you could just simply put and h ref="#page2"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Jasper's answer fixed my issue and I understand quite well the logic now. I will save jqm events for later ;)